# I am an Indian passport holder studying on F1 visa in USA ,want to travel Dubai for ten days, how to get Visa?

Tags: visas, uae

I am an Indian passport holder and at present studying in USA on F1 visa. In winter break I want to visit my relatives living in Dubai for ten days and than come to India. what is the procedure for getting UAE travel visa?

Comment: Where would you be staying in Dubai, in hotels, or with your family? And would you be flying there on Emirates, or some other airline? (Emirates have a special visa service)

Comment: @Gagravarr Isn't the Emirates visa valid only for up-to 72 hours or so?

Comment: @edocetirwi They offer a few different ones. You can use their special website to apply for a normal tourist visa as well, including ones for > 7 days